# User card display seems to fail on StackApps.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackapps

When hovering over a user on StackApps, I think it tries to display the user card, but fails in doing so (as depicted below.) Perhaps you have forgotten to update CSS?

http://phpcode.eu/images/1314869911.png

Comment: Um, you have a specific link? Looks fine in general to me.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: http://stackapps.com/search?q=sky - hover over his profile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whaddaya know; stuff looks ugly without CSS styling...

Fixed in the next build; I have disabled the user popups on Stack Apps until then.